# TFS One Solution per database?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, tfs, sql-server-data-tools

When putting many (dozens) of databases under source control (TFS,SSDT,VS), do we create one project/solution per database or do we group several databases (i.e. per server) into one (if so, how)?
Thank's

Comment: You can have multiple database into one solution, but you don't have to. We like to put databases that are strongly related into the same solution.

Comment: We use one solution per database. I prefer having them completely separate for easier troubleshooting.

Comment: I guess we will have to learn by trying ourselves. Thanks again for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer having one solution for a related set of databases that get managed/developed together.